# Unable to use livepatch on new Ubuntu 18.04 instance on AWS

Tags: kernel, amazon-ec2

I just tried to install livepatch on my EC2 Ubuntu 18.04 LTS instance running on AWS. Here's the error message I got:

> 2018/10/12 15:24:29 cannot use livepatch: your kernel "4.15.0-1021-aws" is not eligible for livepatch updates

I see that the latest stable kernel version is currently 4.18.13 and the latest longterm version is 4.14.75. Is this a problem that will likely resolve itself over time or is this permanent?
Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

Canonical's livepatch will only work for Canonical kernels based only.

"*-aws" kernels are made by Amazon, and considered as non-Canonical based kernels.

At their [Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Livepatch) they mention:

> GA generic and lowlatency kernel variants only

Hope it works.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense.It would be nice if they manage to expand livepatch to aws kernels some time soon, too.