# Why has the latest Ubuntu Pro AMI and unsupported Kernel

Tags: kernel, 22.04, aws, ubuntu-pro

## Short

The latest ubuntu pro AMI in eu-central-1  has an unsupported Kernel which has reached the end of its livepatch support.

Which AMI should I use to start a recent, working LTS 22.04 Pro Ubuntu, and how do I find it?

## What I Did

I try to spin up a **Ubuntu Pro 22.04** on AWS.
Based on

```
aws ec2 describe-images --region eu-central-1 --owner 099720109477 \
      --filters "Name=name,Values=ubuntu-pro-server/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-*22.04-amd64*" \
      --query 'sort_by(Images, &CreationDate)[-1].{Name: Name, ImageId: ImageId, CreationDate: CreationDate}'
```

I have choosen the following AMI:

```
{
    "Name": "ubuntu-pro-server/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-jammy-22.04-amd64-pro-server-20240207",
    "ImageId": "ami-0b251af482d61fa8e",
    "CreationDate": "2024-02-07T04:14:19.000Z"
}
```

AND started an instance from it. After login I see:

```
*** System restart required. Kernel is no longer supported ***
```

Also `pro status` warns me:

```
The current kernel (6.2.0-1018-aws, x86_64) has reached the end of its livepatch support.
```

A reboot does not fix this.

Given this AMI is just 9 days old and published from canonical and a "Long Term Support", this is unexpected.

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/a/1087181/112263

Comment: AWS images roll an AWS kernel variant.  That is not matching the same standard kernel on the system, and there may be a newer variant available.  If not, then just using the generic kernel might work to solve this.

Comment: I tried again today and *now* the latest AMI has 6.5.0-1014-aws as a kernel and does support live patch. So I guess there has been period where supported was dropped for the older kernel and the  AMI's have not yet been updated to a working one.

Answer (score 1):

What i understand is if you are using one of the AWS kernels livepatch wont support it.

you can disable it using
`sudo pro disable livepatch` or `sudo snap run canonical-livepatch disable`

my understanding of this was from this answer here:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1087181/112263

Comment: This marketing video shows kernel livepatch with aws-kernels for ubuntu workspaces: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W88eCZv1F4g 
So I still have some hope.

Comment: Also https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch/docs/livepatch/reference/kernels lists
6.2 aws variant as livepatch supported